# Duda con un IF ELSE

Tags: php, mysql, condiciones, else

Estoy haciendo un carrito para la web, y hay una cosa que tengo que comparar cuando añado un producto en el carrito.
Si el producto que añado al carrito es de `alquiler = id1` mostrare un `<div>` y si el producto que añado es cualquier otro que lleva otra id pues muestro otro `<div>`.

Vale lo he diferenciado así en el PHP:

```
 if($mitipo == 1){
   echo "<div class=\"row justify-content-between\">
   <div class=\"col detaCart\">Kit iniciación</div>
   <div class=\"col-3 text-right detaCart\">99€</div>
   </div>
     <div class=\"txtGafas\">Gafas técnica, gafas paciente, garrafa de Gel conductor, caja de cuchillas</div>
     <div class=\"row justify-content-between\">
     <div class=\"col detaCart\"><small class=\"smallKit\">¿Incluir kit?</small></div>
     <div class=\"col-3 text-right detaCart ui form\">
     <div class=\"inline field\" style=\"vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;\">
     <div class=\"ui checkbox posCheck\">
        <input type=\"checkbox\" tabindex=\"0\" class=\"hidden\">
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>";

      }else{
      echo "<div class=\"row justify-content-between\">
      <div class=\"col detaCart\">Kit iniciación</div>
      <div class=\"col-3 text-right detaCart\">Incluido</div>
     </div>
     <div class=\"txtGafas\">Gafas técnica, gafas paciente, garrafa de Gel conductor, caja de cuchillas</div>";
     }
```

Lo que hago con eso es decirle si el producto que esta en la variable carrito trae la `ID:1` muéstrame este `<div>` si es cualquier otro muéstrame el otro, pero claro si añado uno cualquiera y luego uno con `ID:1` me lo hace correcto y me cambia el `<div>` del carrito, pero si lo hago al revés, ejp; añado uno con `Id:1` y luego otro cualquiera me quita ese `<div>` y me poner el otro.

Cómo puedo decirle siempre que exista un producto con la `Id:1` siempre salga ese `<div>`???

Comment: Puedes crear una variable antes del if $hay_alquiler=0; a la cual le das valor 1 si el tipo es 1, y la condición de tu if de alquiler sería ($mitipo == 1 || $hay_alquiler==1), de modo que si cumple cualquiera de estas condiciones se muestre el div de alquiler.

Comment: Antes de hacer el if deberías comprobar si existe un producto id 1 en los elementos de tu carro. Con un for y un if lo arreglas.

Comment: Gracias a los dos, me podeis poner un ejemplo?

Comment: Te pongo un ejemplo

Comment: Alguien que me ayude por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final ya lo consegui, la cosa no iba mal encaminada pero habia que sacar el for del HTML.

```
 if(isset($mi_carrito) && count($mi_carrito) != 0){
  // Por defecto establecemos que no debe incluir kit.
  $puedeIncluirKit = false;
  $cantidadProductosParaKit = 0;
  for ($i=0; $i<count($mi_carrito); $i++) {
  // Con almenos 1 objeto del carrito que sea tipo = 1, indicamos que puede incluir kit. y frenamos el ciclo.
     if ($mi_carrito[$i]['Tipo'] == 1) {
     $puedeIncluirKit = true;
     $cantidadProductosParaKit ++;

      }
    }
    // Si existe la variable en true, mostrarmos el div de incluir kit.
    if ($puedeIncluirKit) {
    $div= "Contenido si es que si";
    }else{
    $div= "Contenido si es que no";
    }
    echo $div.""; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ejemplo añadiendo una variable externa al recorrido de los productos del carrito que cambie en el momento que alguno de los productos sea de alquiler.

```
$tipos = array(1,2); //array con los tipos de productos

//tu caso
for ($i=0; $i<count($tipos); $i++) {
    if ($tipos[$i]==1) {
        $div = "alquiler<br>";
    } else {
        $div = "otros";
    }
}
echo $div."<br>"; //otros

//con variable externa
$hay_alquiler=0;
for ($i=0; $i<count($tipos); $i++) {
    if ($tipos[$i]==1 || $hay_alquiler == 1) {
        $div = "alquiler<br>";
        $hay_alquiler = 1;
    } else {
        $div = "otros";
    }
}
echo $div."<br>"; //alquiler
```

Comment: por que pones $div?

Comment: Esque ahora @Carmen no imprime nada

Comment: @Miguel sólo es un ejemplo para que veas la estructura, donde pone $div lo reemplazas por todo lo que tienes dentro del tu if / else.

Comment: Vale faltaba alguna modificación. Pero sigue pasandome lo mismo, si meto uno primero con id1 y luego otro me desaparece el div del 1. Lo bueno que tiene lo que me has pasado es que si no hay ningun producto en el carrito ese div desaparece

Comment: Para que no te pase la variable $hay_alquiler debe estar fuera del código que reemplaces al meter el nuevo producto para que se mantenga. Si recorres los productos de tu carrito con un bucle, antes del bucle.

Comment: Pero lo hice de la primera forma que me pusiste, tengo que hacerlo con la segunda?

Comment: Listo, tube que hacer unos cambios, voy a publicarlo en una respuesta

Comment: Nada @Carmen, pensaba que lo tenia pero haciendolo así for ($i=0; $i<count($mi_carrito); $i++) {
                        if ($mitipo[$i]<=1) { cuenta el numero de registros

Comment: ¿Qué hay en el array $mi_carrito y en $mitipo? Porque lo lógico sería que cada elemento de $mi_carrito (cada producto) tuviera un propiedad 'mitipo'.

Comment: En teoria, y digo en teoria ya que es la primera vez que preparo un carrito; $mi_carrito contabiliza los productos que hay dentro del carro y $mitipo es la id que viene al traer un producto al carro

Comment: ¿Pero son arrays que es lo esperado? Haz un var_dump($mi_carrito) y var_dump($mitipo)

Comment: Lo que te comentaba, el $mi_carrito trae todo lo que tenga el carrito en ese moemento, y lo otro la id que se carga al añadir un producto

Comment: Debería funcionar con for ($i=0; $i<count($mi_carrito); $i++) { if ($mitipo[$i]==1 || $hay_alquiler == 1) { , no olvides actualizar la variable $hay_alquiler (o el equivalente que hayas usado)

Comment: Lo probe de nuevo y sigue sin funcionar!

Comment: Nada no hay forma @Carmen llevo todo el día con esto y nada, puedes ayudarme?

Comment: @Miguel con la info disponible no veo el problema, sería necesario editar la pregunta y ver el código al añadir productos al carrito para ver dónde está.

Comment: Hola ya esta solucionado mira mi respuesta @Carmen. Muchas gracias.